# Import all files from a folder into Access 2016 using VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm trying to import some txt files from a folder but i can't find out what the command is to import all files that are in a folder.

```
DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, , "tab1", "C:\example", True
```

thats my code..

Does anyone know that?

(Sorry, I'm very new to VBA).

**EDIT :**

**This question is Irelevant and does not have a purpose anymore!
it was an internal script mistake!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As usual, the solution to solving a complex problem is to split it into simple problems:

1. [Loop through all the `*.txt` files in the folder](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10380312/87698) (the second, highest-voted answer shows how to use wildcards).
2. Import the file (you already have code for that).